# Help understanding proof on Wikipedia "Mediant" page

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

Suppose $a,b,c,d\geq 0$ and that $ad-bc=1$

on [This Wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediant_(mathematics)#Properties) it says

$$
\frac{\lambda_1 a+\lambda_2 b}{\lambda_1 c +\lambda_2 d} -\frac{a}{c} = \lambda_2 \frac{bc-ad}{c(\lambda_1 c +\lambda_2 d)}
$$
and 
$$
\frac{b}{d} -\frac{\lambda_1a+\lambda_2 b}{\lambda_1 c +\lambda_2 d} = 
\lambda_1 \frac{bc-ad}{d(\lambda_1c +\lambda_2 d)}
$$
must be positive (OK),

Then it says, because $ad-bc=1$, it must be that

- $\lambda_1,\lambda_2$ are integers
- solving the system of linear equations
  $$
  a'=\lambda_1a+\lambda_2b\\
  c'=\lambda_1c+\lambda_2d
  $$
- Therefore $c'\geq c+d$

**I am confused on 1), 2), and 3)**

- specifically, why must $\lambda_1,\lambda_2$ be integers (that solve that system of linear equations), and why can they not be negative integers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, it's $bc-ad$ which equals 1, not $ad-bc$, so the reason $\lambda_2>0$ is because

$$0< a'/c'-a/c= \frac{\lambda_1a+\lambda_2b}{\lambda_1c+\lambda_2d}-\frac{a}{c}$$
which simplifies to $\frac{\lambda_2}{cc'}>0$ when you use the fact that $bc-ad=1$ and $c'=\lambda_1c+\lambda_2d$. Since $c,c'$ are assumed to be $>0$, you must have $\lambda_2>0$. The argument for $\lambda_1$ is similar.

Now solve
$$
a'=\lambda_1a+\lambda_2b\\
c'=\lambda_1c+\lambda_2d
$$
to get $\lambda_1$ in terms of $a',a,b,c',c,d$. You will get an expression that makes it clear $\lambda_1$ is an integer (when you use the fact that $bc-ad=1$).

Finally you have $c'=\lambda_1 c+\lambda_2d$ where $\lambda_1\geq 1$ and $\lambda_2 \geq 1$, which gives the inequality you want.

Comment: About "when you use the fact that $bc-ad=1$ and $c'=\lambda_1c+\lambda_2d$: The statement in theorem on the Wiki says "if the fraction $\frac{a'}{c'}$ lies strictly in between $\frac{a}{c} + \frac{b}{d}$, then...$c'=\lambda_1c+\lambda_2d$. **So the only assumption we have is that** the fraction $\frac{a'}{c'}$ lies strictly in between $\frac{a}{c} + \frac{b}{d}$. **Where can I see that this assumption implies** that there is such a $c'$ (and $a'$) such that $c'=\lambda_1c+\lambda_2d$?

Comment: just solve the equations thinking of $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ as unknowns: there is a solution because of the determinental condition.